# first argument must be an iterable of pandas objects, you passed an object of type "DataFrame" - not sure why

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I have the following code below. I am trying to concatenate columns together and fill an empty dataframe 'emptyframe'.

The idea is that I start with 3 columns, then add on another 3 columns, then another 3 colums etc...

```
emptyframe = pd.DataFrame()

for j in range(0,len(df.columns)):
    newdata = pd.concat((newdf.loc[:,j],happydf.loc[:,j],motivedf.loc[:,j]),axis=1)
    emptyframe = pd.concat(newdata,emptyframe)

print(emptyframe)
```

However, the following code gives me the error 'first argument must be an iterable of pandas objects, you passed an object of type "DataFrame"'.

As an example:

```
newdata = pd.concat((newdf.loc[:,0],happydf.loc[:,0],motivedf.loc[:,0]),axis=1)
```

Gives me:

```
  0    0    0
0        NaN  NaN  NaN
1        NaN  NaN  NaN
2        NaN  NaN  NaN
3        NaN  NaN  NaN
4        NaN  NaN  NaN
5   fullMiss   37   66
6   nearMiss   33   67
7        hit   75   60
8   fullMiss   36   63
9        hit   74   42
10  nearMiss   19   45
11  fullMiss   24   28
12  fullMiss   13   20
13  nearMiss    2    9
14  fullMiss    8    9
15  fullMiss    3    4
16  nearMiss   52    5
17  fullMiss   49    2
18  fullMiss   52    3
19  fullMiss   52    0
20       hit   50   10
21  nearMiss   59    3
22       hit   52    2
23  fullMiss   54    4
24  nearMiss   35    1
25  fullMiss   49    0
26  nearMiss   51   13
27  fullMiss   54    9
28  nearMiss   53    4
```

I would be so grateful for a helping hand!

As an example, the first 10 lines of 'newdf':

```
         0         1         2         3         4         5         6   ...        71        72        73        74        75        76        77
0       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  ...       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
1       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  ...       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
2       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  ...       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
3       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  ...       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
4       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  ...       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
5  fullMiss  fullMiss  fullMiss  fullMiss  fullMiss       hit  fullMiss  ...  fullMiss  fullMiss  nearMiss  nearMiss  fullMiss  nearMiss  fullMiss
6  nearMiss  nearMiss  nearMiss  nearMiss  nearMiss  fullMiss  nearMiss  ...  nearMiss  nearMiss       hit  fullMiss       hit  fullMiss  nearMiss
7       hit       hit       hit  fullMiss  fullMiss  nearMiss  fullMiss  ...       hit       hit  fullMiss       hit  fullMiss       hit  fullMiss
8  fullMiss  fullMiss       hit  fullMiss  fullMiss  fullMiss  fullMiss  ...  fullMiss  nearMiss  fullMiss  nearMiss  nearMiss  fullMiss  nearMiss
9       hit  fullMiss       hit  nearMiss  nearMiss  fullMiss  fullMiss  ...  nearMiss  nearMiss       hit       hit  fullMiss  nearMiss  fullMiss
```

happydf:

```
    0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10   11   12   13  ...   64   65   66   67   68   69   70   71   72   73   74   75   76   77
0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  ...  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  ...  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  ...  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
3  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  ...  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
4  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  ...  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
5   37   31   48   32   17   70    6    3   22   52   20   99   51   29  ...    3   51   52   50   18   28   22   52   35   36    1    9    4   20
6   33   42   39   35   34    8   15    0   23   49   67   50   50   29  ...   49   50   41   43   54   39   35   35   16   68    0   89    0   62
7   75   75   65   36   52   20    4    0   28  100   34   49   47   28  ...   97   42  100   43   20   36  100   43   23   28   99   21   30   35
8   36   63   70   33   53    1    5   50    7   18   29    1   64   74  ...   50   46   50   45   19   72   58   30   48   12    3   54    0   38
9   74   32   58   35   30   16    8   49   83   50   30    1   51   39  ...   48   39   31   39   12   37   42   59   18   68   88   12    5   33
```

motivedf

```
    0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10   11   12   13  ...   64   65   66   67   68   69   70   71   72   73   74   75   76   77
0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  ...  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  ...  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  ...  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
3  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  ...  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
4  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  ...  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
5   66   50   65   62   17   35   46   95   51   72   51    0   56   24  ...   79   26   82   25   76   25   69   51   86   15   71   66    2   60
6   67   44   60   51   40   67   46   49   52   74   50    0   58   26  ...   85   24   48   24   77   34   62   64   66   50   63   70    4   64
7   60   58   67   39   45   52   48    0   52   95   53    0   51   24  ...   83   11   66   28   76   28   90   63   45   23   71   53   55   50
8   63   44   67   34   52    0   48   53   52   50   53    0   55   41  ...   51   10   28   28   51   72   65   62   50    0   62   50    4   62
9   42   44   58   28   50   69   52   50   52   49   51    1   53   32  ...   39    0   52   45   35   16   45   64   31   15   69   39    3   49
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the 'append' function to solve this issue:

```
emptyframe = pd.DataFrame()

for j in range(0,len(df.columns)):
    newdata = pd.concat((newdf.iloc[:,j],happydf.iloc[:,j],motivedf.iloc[:,j]),axis=1)
    emptyframe = emptyframe.append(newdata) 

print(emptyframe)
```

:)